# PHP function is not returning all the data in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a function

```
    function get_table_content(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 0";
$result = $this->query($sql);
while ($row = $this->fetch($result)){
return ($row);
}
}
```

The problem is, when i call this function it only return the first entry in my database.
How can i make this work it suppose to return about all the data in the table.
I have also tried this and it is not working too

```
    function get_table_content(){
    global $database_connection;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    return ($row);
    }
    }
```

I think the best way to go about this is to return an array and do my foreach operation on it but i can not get it to work.

Can someone help me out Please.
P.S i will preffer it to return an array of all the data in the data so i can do a foreach operation on it.
Thank you

Comment: since you use return that's why you are getting only one record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, in the `while` loop after fetching one row from the result set you're returning the result from the function, and hence you're getting only the first row from the result set. Either use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function or an array in the `while` loop to store the result.

**Method(1):**

```
function get_table_content(){
    global $database_connection;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);

    return mysqli_fetch_all($result);
}
```

**Method(2):**

```
function get_table_content(){
    global $database_connection;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);

    $r = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $r[] = $row;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: When i use method(2) and call the function I get an NOTICE: Array to string in (PATHNAME)... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Ukor I tested both of these methods and it's working fine for me. In which line you're getting this error? *NOTICE: Array to string...* means may be you're trying to `echo` out an array. Do `var_dump(get_table_content());` to debug the issue.

Comment: The both method are working, i think my problem is looping through the array and echoing them.

Answer (score 5):

`return` immediately stops execution of your function during the first iteration of the loop.  To get all records and return them:

```
$result = mysqli_query($database_connection, $sql);
return mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

Side note: This is less efficient then returning a result set resource and looping through it as needed outside your function.  `fetch_all` must convert all results to array, then presumably you're looping through this array later.

Comment: Am sorry, i still don't get, are you saying i should remove the while loop or use the return statement outside the while loop... Please help me understand.

Comment: @Ukor Yes, you can remove the `while` loop and simply call `mysqli_fetch_all` to get the whole resultset in one array and return it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a return inside of your `while` loop, which is terminating that loop and returning the first row of data.

Comment: where is solution? you are in a hurry of posting answers.